# Convert server's default timezone to local user time using moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How do I convert server's default timezone which is set as `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai');` to the user's local time. This is the dateTime value `"created_date":"2020-11-11 17:20:44"` I'm getting from server. What modification do I need to add below to get the user's local time?

```
getTimeFormat(date) {
    return moment(date).format("hh:MM A");
  }
```

Comment: And what exactly do you expect instead? If it’s a 24-hour time, rather than a 12-hour time, then please [read the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). `hh` is for a 12-hour based hour, `HH` for the 24-hour based one. If the `created_date` itself doesn’t have the right timezone, then what have you tried to correct the timezone?

Comment: Sorry I've updated my question. Ohkay, so if I'm getting the date time like this then it is not possible to convert it into user's local time right? Could you show me an example of right way to do this ? @user4642212

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

```js
const created_date = "2020-11-11 17:20:44";
// take the date and create a moment using its local timezone
const dubs = moment.tz(created_date, "Asia/Dubai");
// now convert to local
const local = dubs.local().format("hh:mm A");

console.log(local);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Also `MM` is month, not minute, which is `mm`

another option would be to format that string as a proper ISO datetime string in the firstplace, so it would then be `2020-11-11T17:20:44.000+04:00` (The `+04:00` here specifies that this time is in the local Dubai time zone, i.e. 4 hours ahead of UTC):

```js
const isoDate = "2020-11-11T17:20:44.000+04:00";

const date = new Date(isoDate);
console.log(`${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}`);
```

You then wouldn't need moment at all.